# Expression result unused when incrementing counter

Tags: c, pointers, operator-precedence

```
void insert(size_t node, queue_t* queue) {
    *queue->count++;
    queue->elements[++(*queue->rear)] = node;
}
void remve(queue_t* queue) {
    *queue->front++;
    *queue->count--;
}
```

I am passing a queue and a node I wish to add to it into these helper functions. However, all the lines which involve an increment throw a "expression result unused" error. I would like to perform operations on this queue in helper functions without this error occuring.

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the definition of `queue_t`.

Comment: Why is `queue->count` a pointer?

Answer (score 2):

An expression like

```
  *queue->front++;
```

get parsed as

```
  *( queue->front++) ;
```

due to [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), so the final result (obtained by applying the dereference operator) is *unused*. That is what compiler is complaining about and my hunch is, it is correct.

Most probably, what you want is

```
       (*(queue->front) )++ ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Statement `*queue->count++` due to operator precedence actually means `*(queue->count++)`, and I wonder why this code does not give a different error message. I assume that `count`, `front`, etc. are integral values; Therefore, `*queue->count` dereferences an integral value, which is not allowed as only pointers can be dereferenced.

I think, what you actually want is `queue->count++`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to cast to void in order to tell the compiler nothing is returned

```
(void)*queue->front++;
```